# How do I check for an exact word or phrase in a string in Python

Tags: python, string

I need to find a way to figure out a way to find the *exact* word in a string.

All the information I have read online has only given me how to search for letters in a string, so

```
98787This is correct
```

will still come back as true in an `if` statement.

This is what I have so far.

```
if 'This is correct' in text:
    print("correct")
```

This will work with any combination of letters before the `This is correct`... For example `fkrjThis is correct`, `4123This is correct` and `lolThis is correct` will all come back as true in the `if` statement. When I want it to come back as true only if it *exactly* matches `This is correct`.

Comment: Strange that you know about `in` operator, and not `==` operator.

Comment: `in` searches for substrings while `==` checks for exact equality. From your question title I got the impression that you are indeed searching for substrings (in which case `in` is correct). But from your text I am getting the impression you actually want to check equality? (In which case `==` is correct)

Comment: I do want to check for substrings, I just want to make sure it's got nothing before it

Comment: What do you mean by "EXACT word"? Do you mean delimited by spaces? Punctuation?

Comment: You can use spaCy PhraseMatcher.  https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#matcher

Answer (score 42):

You can use the word-boundaries of regular expressions. Example:

```
import re

s = '98787This is correct'
for words in ['This is correct', 'This', 'is', 'correct']:
    if re.search(r'\b' + words + r'\b', s):
        print('{0} found'.format(words))
```

That yields:

```
is found
correct found
```

For an exact match, replace `\b` assertions with `^` and `$` to restrict the match to the begin and end of line.

Comment: what if I want assign true/false to a new column that matches instead of print statement? How should I approach?

Answer (score 16):

Use the comparison operator `==` instead of `in` then:

```
if text == 'This is correct':
    print("Correct")
```

This will check to see if the whole string is just `'This is correct'`. If it isn't, it will be `False`

Comment: That's not correct, since i need it to check a sentence... not jut the one string... so the sentence could be This is a great day and This is correct!

Answer (score 13):

Actually, you should look for 'This is correct' string surrounded by word boundaries.

So

```
import re

if re.search(r'\bThis is correct\b', text):
    print('correct')
```

should work for you.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect that you are looking for the `startswith()` function. This checks to see if the characters in a string match at the start of another string

```
"abcde".startswith("abc") -> true

"abcde".startswith("bcd") -> false
```

There is also the `endswith()` function, for checking at the other end.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a few changes.

```
elif 'This is correct' in text[:len('This is correct')]:
```

or

```
elif ' This is correct ' in ' '+text+' ':
```

Both work. The latter is more flexible.

Comment: Second option seems to work but not the first option. Py3.5

Comment: The first snippet is just a stupid way of writing `text.startswith('This is correct')`.

Comment: What if I have a sentence like `'This is correct.'` and I want to match `correct`, even the second one would fail to match if I don't insert a space between `correct` and `.` (full-stop). Or even `This` would not get matched since there is no space at the start of the sentence.

Comment: That's it. The trick is the spaces

Answer (score 0):

It could be a complicated problem if we want to solve it without using regular expression. But I came up with a little trick.

- First we need to pad the original string with whitespaces.
- After that we can search the text, which is also padded with whitespaces.

**Example code here:**

```
incorrect_str = "98787This is correct"
correct_str = "This is a great day and This is correct"

# Padding with whitespaces
new_incorrect_str = " " + incorrect_str + " "
new_correct_str = " " + correct_str + " "

if " This is correct " in new_correct_str:
    print("correct")
else:
    print("incorrect")
```

Answer (score -1):

Break up the string into a list of strings with .split() then use the in operator.

This is much simpler than using regular expressions.

Answer (score -1):

Below is a solution without using regular expressions. The program searches for exact word in this case 'CASINO' and prints the sentence.

```
    words_list = [ "The Learn Python Challenge Casino.", "They bought a car while at 
    the casino", "Casinoville" ]
    search_string = 'CASINO'
    def text_manipulation(words_list, search_string):
        search_result = []
        for sentence in words_list:
            words = sentence.replace('.', '').replace(',', '').split(' ')
            [search_result.append(sentence) for w in words if w.upper() == 
              search_string]
        print(search_result)

    text_manipulation(words_list, search_string)
```

This will print the results - ['The Learn Python Challenge Casino.', 'They bought a car while at the casino']