# How to check if string contains exact match of string?

Tags: python, string, pattern-matching

I'm trying to check if my dict keys can be found in a string. The thing is that my code doesn't match the entire string as such but goes through each character.

I tried like so:

```
val_dict= {'1/2 pint': 'half', '1': 'one', '5': 'five'}
text = 'I need 1/2 pint of beer'
for x in val_dict:
    if x in text:
        print(x, val_dict.get(x))
```

But I'm getting

```
1/2 pint half
1 one
```

Instead of only 'half'. How to solve it? '/' is not an escape character as far as I know.

Edit:
Given the solutions provided in other topics, I tried regular expressions:

```
for x in val_dict:
    if re.search(rf"\b{x}\b", text, re.IGNORECASE):
        print(x + " match")

>>> 1/2 pint match
>>> 1 match
```

which is ok, because of `\b` but:

```
for x in val_dict:
    if re.search(rf"^{x}$", text, re.IGNORECASE):
        print(x + " match")
```

Should match exact occurrence, but gives no result. Why?

Please note that my dict keys may contain spaces, so splitting the text by spaces won't work.

Comment: 1/2 is in the text, so is 1.

Comment: is there a space after they keys though?   can "1/2pint" occur?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check for an EXACT word in a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632491/how-do-i-check-for-an-exact-word-in-a-string-in-python)

Comment: @ChristianSloper it may occur as well, but for now the main issue is the space between

Comment: You should probably tell us the bigger idea behind what you're trying to do. Your code does find exact matches and works properly, your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @Harvastum what do you mean? the problem is that `1` is matched for `1/2` while OP only wants "*full-word*" matches (which is already answered in the link above)...

Comment: You're first to mention *word matches*. It should be added to the question it that's OP's intent.

Comment: Why do you think `^{x}$` would work? `^` means start of string and `$` means the end of it. So basically you're matching that the whole string is the key which is not what you are trying to do...

Comment: as far as I thought, I was looping through dict keys, so 'x' being a key should be matched against the text string.

Comment: Yes it does indeed, but the pattern `^{x}$` means a string which is just that key. IF you want that key anywhere in the string as a whole word, you need `\b{x}\b`...

Answer (score 1):

This is the fix:

```
val_dict= {'1/2': 'half', '1': 'one', '5': 'five'}
text = 'I need 1/2 pint of beer'
for x in val_dict:
    if x in text.split(' '):
        print(x, val_dict.get(x))
```

**Output**

```
1/2 half
```

Comment: unfortunately this won't work as my dict keys may contain spaces as well

Comment: @jabba see  the above link I provided. Your question is already answered on this site. Either mark it as a duplicate or delete it...

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Regular Expressions

```
import re

val_dict= {r'1/2': 'half', r'1[!/]': 'one', '5': 'five'}
#          ^"1/2"^          ^ 1 with NO SLASH

text = 'I need 1/2 pint of beer'
for x in val_dict:
    if re.match(x, text):
        print(x, val_dict.get(x))
```

Expected output:

```
1/2 half
```

You can tailor RegEx to much better fit your needs!

Comment: match only matches from start of string, you probably meant search