# Finding certain word in text

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a simple question about finding certain word in text.
I want to find the lines of text which contain only "dog" word (not "doggy","doggo" etc.) and print them.
I just want to use the simplest capabilities of Python.

**Note:** this task can't use regex or re library

```
import sys

word = "dog"

for line in sys.stdin:
  x = line.find(word)
  if x != -1:
    print (line)
```

What should I change in this code?

Comment: Just use regex. It is much MUCH simpler, and that's what you would use in a real-world scenario.

Comment: I would do it if I could but it's not a task question

Comment: You should edit to reflect this task can't use regex or re library

Comment: Yup, sorry. This is my second post on Stack so I'm still learning how to use it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this if it helps:

```
  import re

  for line in sys.stdin:
      y= re.findall('\\bdog\\b', line)
      if(len(y)!=0):
          print(line)
```

Later I saw the comment, that you can't use regex or re.

Then, try another approach of loops:

```
   fixed_word="dog"
   for line in sys.stdin:
       word_list=line.split(' ')
       for word in word_list:
           if(word.lower() == fixed_word):
               print(line)
```

Comment: Fails with "I have a dog, a cat, and a parakeet." A better strategy would be to split on any of the characters that the regex `'\b'` matches

Comment: I found a solution with split() function! :) Thank you for your time and help :)

Answer (score 1):

**Using Python map()**

How to find a certain word or words and returns sentence using python map() without importing any libraries like re or others.

```
sentence = ['hi little doggy doggo', 'what is a doggo', 'Benji is my dog'] 
words = ['dog']


 def find(sentence, words): 
        res = list(map(lambda x: all(map(lambda y:y in x.split(), 
                                            words)), sentence)) 
        return [sentence[i] for i in range(0, len(res)) if res[i]] 
        



print(find(sentence, words)) 

['Benji is my dog']
```

You could also find multiple words too if you need.

```
words = ['doggo', 'doggy'] 

print(find(sentence, words)) 



['hi little doggy doggo']
```

Note that this approach fails if dots or commas are part of the sentence. If the last sentence was 'Benji is my dog. He is a good boy.', the split-function returns 'dog.' and consequently does not exactly match 'dog' anymore.

Comment: the find with the comma or period goes beyond my novice knowledge without importing a lib

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can look for all instances of `"dog"`. Then, make sure the character before and after the match aren't letters. The code below is not particularly efficient, but you can come up with a more efficient algorithm to implement the same idea.

```
lines = ["I have a dog", "I have a dog.", "I have a dog, a cat, and a parakeet.", "Doggy dog hotdog", "Hotdog doggy"]
word = "dog"
alphabet = {chr(i) for i in range(97, 97+26)}
for line in lines:
    x = 0
    while x >= 0: # loop while word is found in line
        x = line.find(word, x) # Look for match after last match
        
        charBefore = (line[x - 1] if x > 0 else "").lower() # Character before match if it exists

        charAfter = (line[x + len(word)] if x + len(word) < len(line) else "").lower() # Character after match if it exists

        if charBefore not in alphabet and charAfter not in alphabet:
            print(line)
            break
        x += 1
```

This gives the output

```
I have a dog
I have a dog.
I have a dog, a cat, and a parakeet.
Doggy dog hotdog
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is answered for instance here [How do I check for an EXACT word in a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632491/how-do-i-check-for-an-exact-word-in-a-string-in-python). Re is your friend here as outlined in the answers given:

```
import re

s = 'doggy doggo'
word = 'dog'
if re.search(r'\b' + word + r'\b', s):
    print('{0} found'.format(word))
print('Now trying a string with dog in it')
s = 'a good dog'
if re.search(r'\b' + word + r'\b', s):
    print('{0} found'.format(word))
```

And then instead of s you simply enter the lines of text you want to check

Comment: Unfortunately in this task I can't use regex or re library :(

Comment: If this question is answered elsewhere, don't add an answer here. Instead, flag / vote to close this one as a duplicate.

Comment: @olczig The `re` module comes with the standard Python installation. Is there a reason you don't want to use it? As long as you're excluding inbuilt modules, why not also exclude `sys`?

Comment: I wish I could use it but this is my university task. I have to use stdin but I can't use any other modules...

Comment: @PranavHosangadi: Since I do not have the required reputation points yet, I cannot flag as duplicate. Getting downvoted because of that fact is not exactly going to help...

Answer (score -2):

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    if 'dog' in line:
        print(line)
```

That's another way to do it.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But it doesn't work the way I want it to. It finds also "doggy" etc.