# Check if word is contained exactly in a Python string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, substring

I have this case:

```
a = "I run away without you"
if "with" in a:
    print("s")
else:
    print("n")
```

This expression is True. But, I want to print "n", because `a` has to have exactly "with" and not a substring.
How can I do this?

Comment: nope, I want to print n because I want that "with" must be in a and I don't want to consider with like a substring of a.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check for an exact word in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632491/how-do-i-check-for-an-exact-word-in-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you mean this:

```py
"with" - True
"without" - False
"with xxx" - True
```

you can try: `if "with" in a.split(" "):`

Comment: `a.split()` will be better.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure I understand the problem you are having but if what you are trying to do is check whether your variable only contains the string "with", then use `==` instead of `in`

Comment: In that case, if I have a list of word, ex: a = ["with", "a", etc] I can't use ==

Comment: @Vinz1396 `str in list` performs an exact match. If your a is a list, `if "with" in a` will only happen if list contains **exactly** with.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).